# Using parseFloat() or parseInt() and regex in JavaScript (converting a CSV file)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, floating-point, integer

I'm converting a CSV file to a local 2D array.  I wanted to know if there is a better way to convert strings to floats/int rather then using regex followed by a parseFloat() / parseInt.

Ideas / Suggestions?

```
// numex() - checkes to see if the string (str) is a number
// returns number.valid (true||false) and number.value = (float||int||string)
numex = function(str){
  number = {};
  number.valid = false;
  number.value = str;
  // if we see a number then convert it to a floating point or integer
  if((number.value.search(/[^0-9^\.^\$^\%^\-^\"^,^ ]+/) < 0) && str.length > 0) {  
    number.valid = true;
    number.value = str.replace(/[^\-^0-9^\.]+/g, ''); // TODO add % coversion code for example if we see a 10% covert it to .1
    if(number.value.search(/[\.]/) >= 0) {  
       number.value = parseFloat(number.value); // replace floating point
    } else {
       number.value = parseInt(number.value); // replace integers
    }
  }
  return number; // number.valid = true or false;
}

var num = numex("1.101");
alert(num.value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use regexp at all. Try this:

```
var num = {};  
num.value = new Number(str);  
num.valid = !isNaN(num.value);
```

Number constructor is more strict than parseInt and parseFloat in that it does not accept strings like `10aaa` or `1.2bbb` so there is no need to perform a regexp check.

Comment: if(isNaN(value) || value == ""){return str;} else { return false; };

Comment: new Number('1,000') -> NaN (This is not universally a failure, but it's what I was trying to solve.)

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the code greatly and used something similar to what LeZuse did.

isNaN(value) || value == ""

https://github.com/designpro/jCSV